# Inquiry of the convergence analysis for a specific fixed-point iteration $x(t+1)=(1-\alpha(t))x(t)+(\frac{\alpha(t)}{\sum_{i=0}^t\alpha(i)})$

Tags: convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems

I am currently working on the convergence analysis for a fixed-point iteration and would like to show the iteration w.r.t. the variable $x(t)\in\mathbb{R}$ can converge to $0$, i.e., $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}x(t)=0$. The iteration follows the dynamics as follows.

$x(t+1)=(1-\alpha(t))x(t)+(\frac{\alpha(t)}{\sum_{i=0}^t\alpha(i)})$,

where $\alpha(t)$ satisfies $\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\alpha(t)=\infty$ and $\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}(\alpha(t))^2<\infty$. $x(t)\in\mathbb{R}$ is a scalar with an arbitrary given initial value $x(0)>0$.

It is well noted that when the term $(\frac{\alpha(t)}{\sum_{i=0}^t\alpha(i)})$ in above iteration is replaced by $(\alpha(t))^2$, then the sequence will converge to 0.

However, it seems to be difficult to evaluate when the term $(\frac{\alpha(t)}{\sum_{i=0}^t\alpha(i)})$ is considered.

I have tried lots of different methods but failed. Does anyone have any idea about this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I did some formatting, but I think you left out a summand.